# Database Schema For Private Messages

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I am trying to implement a private messaging system in rails and I need help with the design of the database. I have read around and I have come up with many valid alternatives, but I was wondering if anyone knew of such a schema that would ultimately be scalable. I appreciate any help or links.

EDIT:
The database schema would basically have two things

1.subject

2.message

I was thinking of implementing two tables

### Messages

subject_text

sender_id

reciever_id

has_many texts

### Texts

content_text

I am in no way any good at database schema but I appreciate the help while I am learning

Comment: Why don't you add in the question the alternatives you came up with?

Comment: basically most of them were very complex to try to explain but the simpler ones are basically very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984750/private-message-database-design I have also edited the question to update what the messaging system would include.

Comment: Are you far enough along in thinking about your features to decide about your schema?  Are any of these features expected for instance: messaging to more than one recipient.  has message been read.  date of message.  confirmation that message has been read.  Also what is 'has_many texts'?

Comment: While you are at it, [here's something interesting to read on](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/16/facebooks-new-real-time-messaging-system-hbase-to-store-135.html) about Facebook's messaging system that stores 135 billion messages/month.

Comment: @AllInOne The messaging system would be very basic one recipient, date of message, and of course the message. The 'has_many texts' is how you describe a relationship between two tables in rails. I did however forget to add 'belongs_to messages' in the texts table.

Comment: @RanhiruCooray Thanks for the link I will be sure to take a look at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple and straight-forward design would be..

```
User
----------------
userID
userName
...
...
...

Messages
---------------
messageID
title
body

User_Messages
----------------
senderID (userID of sender)
recieverID (userID of reciever)
messageID (messageID of relative message)
```

This design will simplify your searches too. You can add or remove columns according to your needs.

Comment: thanks for the help, im a noob at rails so please forgive many questions but how would you connect this in the models?

Comment: initially I was asking if you knew how to implement this schema in ruby on rails, but I noticed that the question is under databases. However your answer was just what I needed I was able to get it working this morning. thanks

Comment: You need to add timestamp. Otherwise new messages will get lost in inbox